# Where is Xcode's build folder?

Tags: xcode, build

Before Xcode 4 the build used to be created in the root folder of my project.
I can no longer find it.

Where can i find the build folder?

Comment: Click on **FILE->PROJECT SETTINGS**.  It tells you the folder there.  **Note the small "arrow" button** - it will open the folder for you in finder. Very handy.

Comment: Seems to have been updated to *File -> Workspace Settings*.

Answer (score 301, accepted):

`~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` is now the default.
You can set the prefs in Xcode to allow projects to specify their build directories.

Comment: Ok, so my build goes into the `.../XCode/DerivedData/` folder, simple enough.  Except that the subfolders seem to be `AppName-asdflkjqwergoobledygook`.  Since I'm building from a script, I'd like to actually *find* the build (so I can package it and send via TestFlight :)  How do I determine which of the many `MyAppName-xxxx`-s is the right one?  Thanks!  (Note to Heath: in this particular case, I don't want to force output with the `CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR` parameter, as it messes-up legacy target dependencies.)

Comment: You can find the setting in Xcode Preferences > Locations > Derived Data

Comment: Build results isn't normally version controlled, so this may actually be an improvement for other IDEs to pick up.

Comment: I like it tbh. No messing about excluding obj bin folders from version control this way. Only problem is finding it, but...google.

Comment: @ArneEvertsson is there any version control system on this planet that doesn't offer a way to ignore build directories? Like.. even a single one?

Comment: @Olie This is correct. It will generate hashes as directory names. To find your specific build just make a note of the time you ran the build output and look at the last modified date either in Finder or with `ls -l` over bash

Answer (score 35):

It should by located in: `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`.

If you changed the defaults, you can see where the build directory is by going to **File->Workspace Settings** then look at *Build Location*

Answer (score 16):

You can configure the output directory using the `CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR` environment variable.

Source: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/0-Introduction/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH1-SW1

Comment: Excellent.  Is there a variable that tells the name of the output folder if I just let XCode do it's thing?  (I mean the random-text after the app name in `.../Xcode/DerivedData`)  Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

[image]

[image]

Configure XCode project settings, it can solve your problem.

Comment: Legacy Build System is deprecated!!!

Answer (score 11):

**Xcode build folder**

**Workspace**

By default `Build location` is in `Derived Data`.

Please note: a path to a product can be **changed** if you delete DerivedData during development process and rebuild it again.

```
Xcode -> Preferences... -> Locations
```

[image]

You can change the location of `Build location`. It will have an effect on the whole workspace

```
File -> Project/Workspace Settings... -> Advanced
```

[image]

**Target**

[`CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW40)

If you want to create an autonomic `Build location` for a target you can change the location:

Xcode v11 and above

```
Add User-Defined Setting -> CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR
```

[image]

Xcode pre v11

```
Project editor -> select a target -> Build Settings -> Per-configuration Build Products Path (CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR) 

//default value
$(BUILD_DIR)/$(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)
```

[image]

You can get next error[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67366513/4770877)

```
Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Answer (score 5):

I wondered the same myself. I found that under File(menu) there is an item "Project Settings". It opens a dialog box with 3 choices: "Default Location", "Project-relative Location", and "Custom location" "Project-relative" puts the build products in the project folder, like before. This is not in the Preferences menu and must be set every time a project is created. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, welcome to stackoverflow. Looks like it's an old question and already has an answer. You are all welcome to post your answer, if you think your answer is different and better than the others. I suggest you to please add 'how your answer is different/better' than others. This will help users distinguishing it from other answers.

Comment: Amit, this answer includes better detail on what the GUI shows currently, which differs from prior.

Answer (score 3):

With a project previously created in Xcode3, I see an intermediate directory under `build/` called `Foo.build` where `Foo` is my project's name, and then in that are the directories you'd expect (Debug-iphonesimulator, Release-iphoneos, etc, assuming you've done a build of that type) containing the object files and products.

Now, I suspect that if you start a *new* project in Xcode4, the default location is under DerivedData, but if you open an Xcode3 project in Xcode4, then Xcode4 uses the build/ directory (as described above). So, there are several correct answers. :-) Under the File menu, Project Settings, you can see you can customize how XCode works in this regard as much or as little as you like.

Answer (score 2):

In case of Debug Running

~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{your app}/Build/Products/Debug/{Project Name}.app/Contents/MacOS

You can find standalone executable file(Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64)

Answer (score 1):

For me it was under:

/Users/{your username}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData...

and NOT in /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData...

Answer (score 1):

You can change the build directory using the project settings, but those settings don't seem to be saved in the shared settings, so it's hard to get them into source control, which makes it difficult to create automated builds that get everything from source control first.

My fix: add scripts to the project to copy the built files to wherever you like. Select the target in Xcode (these instructions are for Xcode 12): click on the file icon in the top left to open the Project Navigator, then on the project name next to an Xcode icon, then on the target in the right-hand pane. Now click on the Build Phases tab, then on the little plus sign, then on 'New Run Script Phase'.

You can type in a script which should be something like this:

```
cp -R ${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/MyProduct.framework ${PROJECT_DIR}/MyProduct.framework
```

This example is for a framework project, so it copies the whole framework directory to the project directory (where your .xcodeproj file lives). Now, when you build on the command line using xcodebuild, your built product will be in a known place.