# Codesign: What are unsealed contents?

Tags: macos, cocoa, xcode6, code-signing

I have just upgraded to XCode 6 and tried to build my Developer ID signed Mac app.
However, I now get the following codesign error:

```
unsealed contents present in the root directory of an embedded framework
```

This applies to the `Dropbox.framework` that I use. Obviously that could not be signed. What does the error mean? What is wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have a look at [OS X Code Signing In Depth](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2206/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007919-CH1-TNTAG205)

Beginning with OS X version 10.9.5, there will be changes in how OS X recognizes signed apps

[Structure your bundle](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/FrameworkAnatomy.html) according to the expectations for OS X version 10.9 or later:

- Only include signed code in directories that should contain signed
  code.
- Only include resources in directories that should contain
  resources.
- Do not use the --resource-rules flag or    ResourceRules.plist. They
  have been obsoleted and will be rejected.

Comment: The second link you gave is about frameworks. What about applications?

Comment: This is weird, b/c I'm getting this error _when I'm trying to code sign XCode 10_. See [here](https://github.com/XVimProject/XVim2/issues/187)

Answer (score 11):

The problem is the `version.txt` file that resides in the `Dropbox.framework`. While this is useful to know which version the framework is, it seems no longer to be OK for codesigning.

When I removed the file everything worked fine again.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. After deleting the version.txt everything works fine

Answer (score 8):

Had the same problem for several hours today, as I tried to adapt a pre-Yosemite .framework bundle to Yosemite.  In the end, the problem was the symlinks I made, not strictly files in the directory.

Initially, the package had a broken symlink in its root directory.  I fixed it up.

The symlink I added:

```
Headers -> Versions/Current/Headers/
```

What it needed to be:

```
Headers -> Versions/Current/Headers
```

That extra slash is the killer.

Note that this bit me twice in two different spots:  I also had

```
Current -> 1.8.0/
```

where I needed

```
Current -> 1.8.0
```

I'm not much of a *nixer, so maybe this is common sense, but hopefully it helps other windows devs like myself.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue today... my error was "unsealed contents present in the bundle root". The fix for me was to remove the custom icon I had on on my app. AppName.app/Icon? was corrupt somehow...

Comment: Or perhaps it was in a directory that should not contain resources. The tech note referenced above states this about the allowed locations for code within a bundle `These places are expected to contain only code. Putting arbitrary data files there will cause them to be rejected.`  Codesign -vvv <yourapp> will reveal the folder that it is rejecting.

Answer (score 1):

I researched this for a while today and none of the suggestions I found helped, my sdl_mixer.framework had five embedded frameworks that I couldn't get past iTunesConnect. My solutions was to remove three of them that I didn't actually need, and the other two were added to my project as standalone frameworks, not embedded in the sdl_mixer. Hopefully this helps someone, I spent hours on this.

Answer (score 1):

I have hit this twice now, so I am adding the causes, since codesign is very opaque and generally refuses to tell you what the problematic resource is.

On one occasion, I had an unsigned binary executable.  Each executable and framework needs to be individually signed before singing the bundle as a whole.

Then I hit another case.  I sign my code as part of the publish process, re-signing each executable and framework.  But Xcode also signs the bundle as well, and it turns out that was leaving cruft behind in _CodeSignature folders. So now, before signing each of the executables and frameworks and then the bundle, I pre-remove Xcode's generated _CodeSignature folders with something like:

```
find MyApp.app -name _CodeSignature -type d -exec rm -rf {} +
```

Hopefully this hard-won information will save someone some time one day.

Comment: The -f option to codesign is supposed to replace all the old signatures. From the man page:


"     -f, --force
             When signing, causes codesign to replace any existing signature
             on the path(s) given. Without this option, existing signatures
             will not be replaced, and the signing operation fails."

Comment: @Phill-Apley My codesign has the --force option.  It was insufficient.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was trying to sign an app with some old frameworks inside. None of these suggestions helped. Turned out I had to remove the PkgInfo file from inside a framework to get this message to go away.

Answer (score 1):

I had such error:

```
<some_path>: unsealed contents present in the bundle root
Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code
```

The issue was that I used a custom `CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57512068/4770877). And after some changes(changing macOS and iOS platforms) it occurred

And when you clean your project this custom location build is not cleaned(like derived data). To solve this problem **remove** content of this folder manually

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and what worked for was deleting the contents of the DerivedData folder. Xcode doesn't say which resource is causing the problem, so I rebuilt everything from scratch. Clean didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the problem when I tried to sign another framework, the answers here are very inspiring, here must be some problems with the framework structure, but I did find any them. The structure seems to be right, the symlinks have not tailling "/", there is not extra file (checking with `ls`) ...

After tons of trying, I finally realized there is a extra `.DS_Store` in the framework, which is really annoying :(

So if you still hit the error, try to check if there is any hidden files.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible cause of this problem: if you are building iOS and macOS apps that have the same name and the same installed location, you may find that both of them are written into the same app bundle. First the iOS app build places its contents directly in the app bundle root, and then the macOS app build places its contents into a "Contents" folder in the app bundle, and then codesign complains about the iOS resources.