# Abc.app unsealed contents are present in the bundle root - Xcode, any change required to bundle?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, xcode5

I have switched my XCode version from 3.2.6 to 5.1.1, I have been asked to change the project settings and porting to a new format and resolved many compilation errors as well.
Now there is no compilation errors i could able to build my project successfully.

When I tries to sign the project using codesign v2 (mac 10.9.5) i could see the following error

> "Abc.app unsealed contents are present in the bundle root"

To Resolve I have gone through the below link and tried to create a bundle structure as mentioned in it, but i'm missing something basically I don't know what it is.

[Codesign: What are unsealed contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25950544/codesign-what-are-unsealed-contents/26068113#26068113)

My folder Structure would be similar to below, if anyone has seen discrepancy kindly mention what i need to correct.

/src/Abc/

- Abc.xcodeproj
- build\
- doc\
- English.proj
- Info.plist
- Installer.pmdoc
- InstallScripts\
- Japanese.lproj\
- Libraries\
- Abc_Prefix.pch
- Abc.pmproj
- Package\
- Resource\

  - *.png, *.icns, *.jpg, setting.plist
- Source\
- Uninstall\
- zh_TW.lproj\

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In my experience, this error message means I've left some files in the same folder level as the Contents folder.

Everything must be inside the Contents folder.

Try moving whatever files are on the same level as the Contents folder to somewhere inside the Contents folder.

Comment: You saved my day!.

Comment: You saved my day as well, it took me hours to find this solution but now it finally works.

Comment: Hi, i'm new.
Where is the Contents folder?

This is my platform: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pTiR2YJSArIwJBsSL-e6nfPMLtuCE5RE/view?usp=sharing

And in Xcode: https://drive.google.com/file/d/15fnABnLSBErSHz14vNk1NxbdtGERjcnE/view?usp=sharing