# unsealed contents present in the bundle root, iOS Application

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, code-signing

When i try to run an iOS Project on Device (Previously developed by someone else), Im getting following code signing error.(I'm Using XCode 7.3 and project is using https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage
https://github.com/devxoul/CocoaSeeds)

```
<App Name>.app: unsealed contents present in the bundle root
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

I tried to add -vvvv parameter expecting more information regarding the issue, but codesign was not giving more information than previous error.

Obviously the project runs on the simulator without any issue,

Any help to get much more information regarding which resource/file make the codesign fails, or any help to resolve the issue would be grateful
Thanks

Comment: Possible repeat of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27145958/abc-app-unsealed-contents-are-present-in-the-bundle-root-xcode-any-change-req