# OSX code signing

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm having trouble to build my application for Application Store.
In the provisioning page I entered the developer id certificate and the installer id certificate (both are the common name of the certificates in my key chain).
When I try to build the application I get the following message:

> unsealed contents present in the bundle root

I'm using XE7.

What am I doing wrong?

@Doug
Thanks for your comment, the only external file I have is a style resource.
This file by default is located on the first directory of the package.
Do I need to move it to the "Resources" folder in the deployment?

Comment: I've never experienced such a problem, but the message seems very self-explanatory.

Comment: This link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25950544/codesign-what-are-unsealed-contents might be of some use. I would recommend not trying to develop signed apps for Apple stores without the latest version of Delphi, because requirements can be changed by Apple. XE7 is now two versions out (XE8, now 10 Seattle).

Comment: Usually that means you deployed one of your user document files in the wrong place inside the bundle.