# unsealed contents present in the bundle - Mac build

Tags: macos, node-webkit, node-webkit-agent

Am trying to signing my app build with nwjs in Mac. 
https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/MAS:-Signing-the-app

Following are the steps i tried. Out of 8 steps upto 7 worked for me. When i run the 8th command am getting 
"unsealed contents present in the bundle root" error message.

```
1. export IDENTITY= "*******" 
2. export PARENT_PLIST=/path/to/parent.plist
3. export CHILD_PLIST=/path/to/child.plist
4. export APP_PATH=/path/to/yourapp/YourApp.app

5. codesign --deep -s $IDENTITY --entitlements $CHILD_PLIST $APP_PATH"/Contents/Frameworks/nwjs Helper.app"

6. codesign --deep -s $IDENTITY --entitlements $CHILD_PLIST $APP_PATH"/Contents/Frameworks/nwjs Helper EH.app"

7. codesign --deep -s $IDENTITY --entitlements $CHILD_PLIST $APP_PATH"/Contents/Frameworks/nwjs Helper NP.app"

8. codesign --deep -s $IDENTITY --entitlements $PARENT_PLIST $APP_PATH
```

Please see the screen shot for my file structure

[image]

Comment: did you check outthe discussion at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25950544/codesign-what-are-unsealed-contents?  It might apply

Comment: Tried but still am getting same error. Thank you

Comment: @Dibish did you got solution for this error ?

Comment: @arpan_techisavy Yes, successfully took build, and submitted the build to MacStore they approved it now. :) . You may check the latest nwjs build in their github and do the steps described there.

Comment: @Dibish what version are you using ? i have same issue and nothing works...