# Embedding files in an iOS app (C++/Qt/cmake)

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, qt, cmake

In an iOS c++/Qt application, I need to ship a few files and to keep them in their directory structure.

For the Android version, we bundle a zip which we unzip on the target before creating the QApplication.

On iOS, it seems that CMake is not capable of bundling files in a tree:
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/RESOURCE.html#prop_tgt:RESOURCE
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION.html

I am not sure if this is a limitation of cmake or if this is a global limitation on iOS.
From the [docs about iOS bundles](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW15):

> It uses a relatively flat structure with few extraneous directories in an effort to save disk space and simplify access to the files.

What would be the preferred approach?

1. Is there a solution to ship the files from CMake directly?
2. If not, how can I achieve this so that they are available before the QApplication is created?

---

**The xcode command**

Thanks to @Cy-4AH, I added the folder in Xcode and could get the command to do this:

```
CpResource _PATH_TO_DIRECTORY_ _APP_BUNDLE_DIRECTORY_/_RESOURCE_DIR_NAME_
cd /Users/denis/opt/qfield/ios/QField
export PATH="....."
builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -strip-debug-symbols -strip-tool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/strip -resolve-src-symlinks _PATH_TO_DIRECTORY_ _APP_BUNDLE_DIRECTORY_
```

But how can I create this from cmake? `builtin-copy`is an xcode command.

---

**Simple system copy command**

From an old (2008) [discussion](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2008-November/025457.html), we could use simple `cp` commands.
This works up to signing, but then I get an error `unsealed contents present in the bundle root`.

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26015699/1548052), it seems related that I cannot simply add folders in the resource directory. From the docs [anatomy of framework bundles](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/FrameworkAnatomy.html): `Nonlocalized resources reside at the top level of the Resources directory`

Comment: Just put in app bundle ‍♂️. You can look in xcode build logs how it copy files into bundle and make same calls with `CMake`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Cy-4AH, this brought me further. But the question still remain on how I can trigger this from cmake without actually doing this in xcode.

Comment: I don't entirely remember how we solved this issue, years back, but I remember I added the files as under source_group in CMake. and from objective-c, I just access it without files so something like [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"txt"];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently the CMake method also works for directories.

```
target_sources(${QT_IOS_TARGET} PRIVATE ${_resource})
set_source_files_properties(${_resource} PROPERTIES MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION Resources)
```

It will just be added at the root directory of the bundle and not within the `Resources`.

Answer (score 1):

(Disclaimer: I'm not a CMake user, and there may be a more CMake-ey way to do this)

If you can set up post-build action, the following terminal script can efficiently sync files into your bundle from another location.  I use it in my game engine because it only copies updated or new files upon subsequent builds, and preserves directory structure:

```
mkdir -p PATHTO/ORIGINFOLDERNAME
mkdir -p PATHTOBUILDFOLDER/PROJECTNAME.app/Contents/Resources/DESTINATIONFOLDERNAME
rsync -avu --delete --exclude=".*" PATHTO/ORIGINFOLDERNAME/ PATHTOBUILDFOLDER/PROJECTNAME.app/Contents/Resources/DESTINATIONFOLDERNAME
```

The `mkdir` commands are only to ensure that the folders are generated, if they were deleted.

Comment: That is actually what is doing Xcode behind its builtin-copy. This would be an acceptable solution. But in the end the cmake command is working will with directories. I am giving you the bounty as this would be a solution. Thanks!

Comment: Oh man, thanks for the bounty!  It's my pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

If the embedded file is not too big, you might consider :

- in your source tree, generating a C++ file embedding that file as a constant array. For example, if your file contains just `hello, world` with a new line, you could have something like

  ```
  /// file contents.cc
  const char file_contents[] = "hello, world\n";
  ```

and at the beginning of your program (perhaps in your `main` function, before your `QApplication`) call a C++ function which writes such a file (perhaps in `/tmp/`).

- in your build automation (e.g your `Makefile` or your qmake things), have something which *generates* the C++ `contents.cc` file from the genuine source

This is with a POSIX/Linux point of view, **adapt my answer to your iOS**.

Comment: This seems quite clumsy. A similar approach would be to join a zip file in the resource and unzip it (to embed several files and a directory structure). Cheers.