# Downloading "Non-App Store" iOS App from iTunes

Tags: ios, xcode

There is a great discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak) about the recent changes that have come from Xcode 7 in regards to deploying an app to your iOS device. It is one of the only sources of information about iOS app deployment that is remotely up-to-date on SO it seems (Issue for Meta I guess...)

I have 2 questions about a particular comment in that post that I was hoping for enlightenment on

> And to distribute an app, just target "Generic iOS Device", hit Build, then grab your .app, drop it into iTunes, and you'll have an IPA, read to distribute however you want. – dadude999

**My first question is**:  Where is the .app file/folder that this user is talking about?

**and my second question**: Will this .app work in anyones iTunes that I provide it to?  Or will it only work with the one that is linked to my Xcode?

***EDIT: First Question Resolved***

Thanks to luk2302 for clarifying that this is indeed the same .app file that has been previously asked about in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952782/where-is-xcodes-build-folder). When I asked, I was unsure about this.  Now, however, my primary concern falls to the second question.

Comment: generally: have you tried asking the user how made the above statement?

Comment: Pretty inactive user... Figured I would have better luck asking the whole community

Answer (score 1):

Regarding question 1:

You normally see that `AppName.app` file in your Xcode and can simply open it in the Finder to see where it is. In my case:

> /Users/myUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SomeAppHash/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/

[image]

Alternatively archive your App, in the archiver choose to show in finder and in there select the "show package contents" option. That would result in the following path:

> /Users/myUser/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2015-12-22/Flip 22.12.15 19.10.xcarchive/Products/Applications

Regarding question 2:

No idea so far, but you could simply try it out, create an demo app, which is just on of the presets, build it and try to get it on someones phone from their iTunes.

Comment: @gnasher729 if he is archiving, yes. Added the option to the answer. I am however not sure what he / the other user was exactly doing.