# How to make Adobe Illustrator use a plug-in built in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, adobe-illustrator

I've got a plug-in written for Adobe Illustrator that I need to debug.  How do I make Adobe Illustrator use the plug-in that Xcode compiles?

I've read [Adobe Illustrator's Getting Started Guide](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/illustrator/sdk/CC2017/getting-started-guide.pdf) but it merely says to set the "Additional Plug-ins Folder".  How do I point the "Additional Plug-ins Folder" to Xcode's build folder for the the plug-in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Adobe Illustrator CC 2017 and Xcode Version 8.3.2 (8E2002), I found the following approach worked.

First I make an alias to the build folder so that I could navigate to it in Adobe Illustrator:

1. Go into Finder
2. Go to Go > Go to Folder
3. Type in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode
4. Right click DerivedData
5. Choose Make Alias
6. Drag the "DerivedData alias" to your desktop

Now that I had an alias, I could go back into Adobe Illustrator:

1. Go to Illustrator CC > Preferences > Plug-ins & Scratch Disks...
2. Check the box "Additional Plug-ins Folder"
3. Click the Choose button
4. Navigate to ~/Desktop and double click the "DerivedData alias"
5. Go up a directory (command+)
6. Select DerivedData
7. Click OK
8. Click OK

With the method above I was able to get the Xcode debugger to attach to Adobe Illustrator and stop on breakpoints in my code.

The post [Where is Xcode's build folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952782/where-is-xcodes-build-folder) helped me locate the build directory.  I confirmed there was an Adobe Illustrator Plugin file in that directory by searching for all files with .aip extension.  There was one, so I assume Adobe Illustrator traverses "Additional Plug-ins Folder" looking for all .aip files.