# Push app file from Travis-CI to github

Tags: swift3, travis-ci, macos-sierra

I am working on a simple **MacOS app** using **Xcode 8.3** in **Swift 3**, the source of which is on Github. I have setup continuos-integration on Travis-CI and it works fine.

What I want to do is automatically generate an **.app** file for my app in the CI where it will be pushed to my Github account (and hence Github pages) automatically. How can I do this? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it's possible. You're currently using Travis CI for continuous build/test, you'll now just use Travis CI for **continuous release** as well.

The easiest way to do continuous release (if you're using Github) is to use [Github Releases](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-releases/). Travis also has [an integration with Github Releases](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/releases/), so if you create a tag, you can automatically upload the .app build artififact to Github Releases.

Comment: Yes, I did come across that. The only problem is I don't know the location of the .app file that is generated. In my local environment, it is outside of my project directory. And I am not able to locate where Travis-CI is generating it. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: @rgamber hopefully this will help  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952782/where-is-xcodes-build-folder

Comment: I did see that as well, though I am not sure how to get the path of the app file on the travis build machine. I tried using `$TRAVIS_BUILD_PATH` but it complained that my file does not exist in that location.

Comment: try using the `tree` command in the output folder, that'll show the entire tree with files. it's probably in a folder called `debug` or something