# What is Xcode test build path?

Tags: xcode

In Xcode, pressing `⌘B` (build target) can build the project, it will generate the build in the path `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{AppName}-{hash}`.

- How could I know the whole path of the build (with the hash value) by a script? Can I find that path in my `.xcodeproj`?
- When I use `⇧⌘U` (build test target only), where can I find the test target build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The build paths can be controlled using `BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR` , `PROJECT_TEMP_DIR` , `CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR`  and `CONFIGURATION_TEMP_DIR`  etc . https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/11.4/#/itcaec37c2a6

There's no need to extract them from some non-public file format specification.

If you must do it, init a temporary git repo with a xcodeproj file in it. Commit it. Make a change in one of the variables and then run `git diff`.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. *How could I know the whole path of the build (with the hash value) by a script?*

1. Change to the same folder where your project or workspace is
2. Run `xcodebuild -showBuildSettings`
3. May need to add the proper scheme or target.  See `man xcodebuild`

See sample below to find by script

> 2. *When I ... build for test target only, where can I find the test target build?*

It will be in the same folder with a name similar to <Test_Target_Name>-Runner.app.  This is useful as you can use for Cloud device testing services.

---

```
# This example works with Xcode project with a single scheme
# Echo to stdout
xcodebuild -showBuildSettings
xcodebuild -showBuildSettings | grep CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR

# save to a variable for use in your script
#   A little brutal, so I'm open to other ways to do this.
CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=$(xcodebuild -showBuildSettings 2> /dev/null | grep CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR | sed 's/[ ]*CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = //')
echo $CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR
```

If you are using Xcode Server Bots

```sh
cd ${XCS_PRIMARY_REPO_DIR}
xcodebuild -showBuildSettings
```

Sample output:

> `/Users/roblabs/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/openmaptiles-ios-demo-eectbiabcmhajpdbcoqnaipiaqpd/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos`

---

As noted in https://stackoverflow.com/a/57512068,

> *The default value is* `$(BUILD_DIR)/$(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)`

---

For further documentation on the build setting properties, see [Build Setting Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html) at developer.apple.com.  The link that @puio listed is also useful.